# Opening and Closing of stomata

Tags: photosynthesis, glucose

Which is the more accepted theory for the opening and Closing of stomata : the sugar concentration theory or the k+ ion theory ?

Comment: I am unaware of these two hypotheses (not theory). For my curiosity (and the curiosity of other readers), can you please link to descriptions of these hypotheses?

Comment: You may want to refer to [this](http://www.biologydiscussion.com/transpiration/stomatal-movement/theories-of-stomatal-movement-4-theories-with-diagram/14896) link.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_cell) states K+ transport as main factor for stomatal opening & closing, which shows that K+ ion pump hypothesis is more widely accepted.